# Removing \chairman in MIT LaTeX thesis template

Tags: templates, texstudio

I am using the [MIT LaTeX thesis templates](http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/) as a template.

On the `cover.tex` page I've tried commenting out / removing the `\chairman` command.

`%\chairman{Arthur C. Smith}{Chairman, Department Committee on Graduate Theses}`

but this leads to an unexpected error:

```
line 91: Undefined control sequence \maketitle
line 91: There's no line here to end. \maketitle
line 91: Undefined control sequence \maketitle
```

What is the root cause of this behavior? It looks to me like somehow some commands (eg. `\thesisdate`, `\degreeyear` etc. are required by this template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your quoting of the error message is misleading, the actual error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@chairmanname 
                          \\ \@chairmantitle 
l.91 \maketitle
```

The undefined command is always the last token on the second line so `\@chairmanname` the later lines show the context where the error was detected which is `\maketitle`.

Note the comments in the file say

```
%% Make the titlepage based on the above information.  If you need
%% something special and can't use the standard form, you can specify
%% the exact text of the titlepage yourself.  Put it in a titlepage
%% environment and leave blank lines where you want vertical space.
%% The spaces will be adjusted to fill the entire page.  The dotted
%% lines for the signatures are made with the \signature command.
```

So what you are intended to do is use `\begin{titlepage}` not `\maketitle` 
alternatively redefine `\maketitle` the original is:

```
\def\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}
\large
{\def\baselinestretch{1.2}\Large\bf \choosecase{\@title} \par}
by\par
{\Large  \choosecase{\@author}}
\par
\@prevdegrees
\par
\choosecase{Submitted to the} \choosecase{\@department} \\
\choosecase{in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the}
\choosecase{\@degreeword} 
\choosecase{of}
\par
\choosecase{\@degree}
\par
at the
\par\MIT\par
\@degreemonth\ \@degreeyear
\par
\@copyrightnotice
\par
\vskip 3\baselineskip
\signature{Author}{\@department \\ \@thesisdate}
\par
\vfill
\unvbox\@titlesupervisor
\par
\vfill
\signature{Accepted by}{\@chairmanname \\ \@chairmantitle}
\vfill
\end{titlepage}}
```

so if you remove

```
 \signature{Accepted by}{\@chairmanname \\ \@chairmantitle}
```

The error will go.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that front-ends such as TeXStudio are not able to sensibly parse error messages.

Comment: @egreg I wasn't aware there were front ends other than emacs

Comment: @egreg At first, it would be the responsibility of latex to _create_ sensible error messages. However, if you have an idea how to sensibly parse error messages, you are welcome to describe it in a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/).

Comment: @TimHoffmann The undefined control sequence is always in the line below the one starting with `! Undefined`; TeXStudio is using the bottom line, which doesn't give precise information.

Comment: @TimHoffmann The undefined error message is not under the control of LaTeX, it is a TeX primitive behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This reply comes much too late for the OP, but since the question is archived, I'll mention that a new MIT thesis template was released in 2023: https://ctan.org/pkg/mitthesis

This new latex template allows dropping the chairman (or thesis "acceptor") simply by omitting the `\Acceptor{..}{..}{..}` command.  To suppress the resultant error message, put `\SuppressAcceptorError` before `\maketitle*`. See the package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mitthesis/mitthesis-doc/mitthesis-doc.pdf) for details about the various commands.